# What are "." and ".." in Windows' directory?

Tags: windows, file, directory

I am writing a program to list out all files in a directory on Windows. I simply use those File Management functions provided but I am curious about the result:

```
Target file is *.*
The first file found is .
The next file found is ..
The next file found is file0
The next file found is file1
...
...
The next file found is fileN
```

So technically, what are these "." and ".." ? I recalled I use "cd .." in cmd to exit to the upper directory. For "cd .", I don't know what is it for.

Comment: "." represents current directory where are you with windows explorer/total commander or other file manager, where ".." represents command to go up 1 level to upper directory as you said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"." is the current directory.

".." is the parent directory.

This is the same as Unix systems. From your output it looks like Windows is treating them as files.

In the past I've used the "." to make sure that the command (what ever it might be) finds the file in the current directory. The following two statements should be identical:

```
run some.exe

run ./some.exe
```

but if you have some weird search rules that looks on the PATH or in C:\Windows first (for example) then they aren't.

I've found these statements:

> - Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory, for example ".\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths.
> - Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a path to represent the parent of the current directory, for example "..\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths.

on the MSDN page on [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but there's no explanation of what they actually are.

The [Wikipedia page on Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) as a little more information, but again doesn't explain how these are actually stored.

Comment: So simply put, it's like a pointer to a directory, but it's stored in a special type of file? Or else why does it have to be shown in the file list?

Comment: @Karl - it looks that way. I'm trying to find a reference that will give a definitive answer, but as you can imagine searching Google for "cd ." isn't getting me very far.

Comment: Windows doesn't treat them as files. `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` will enumerate them but if you ask them for their attributes you'll discover they are directories.

Comment: Ultimately these things are all just names for objects in the file system namespace. They are never files or directories, just names of those things. And of course a single object has an infinite number of different names (using `..`)!

Answer (score 1):

The single dot represents the current working directory.
The double dot represents the current working directory's parent directory.

Neither of these represent a concrete 'file' in the underlying file system, but represent the directory's location within the file system hierarchy. Although you don't mention it, the '/' symbol, on its own, is similar to these in that it generally represents the root of a particular file system. ie

```
cd /
```

will take you to the root of the current file system.

Rather, the '.' and '..' are references to available resources within the file system, and as such are pseudo-files or pseudo-references generated by the request for file information to the underlying file system and are included to aid navigation around the file system. They are generally OS independent ie. most OS systems respect their use.

You say you are 'writing a program'. Many file management routines that retrieve directory listings include a switch or a method which ignores these pseudo-files when generating directory listings.

However, its normally easiest to write your program to iterate over the entries and ignore these directory entries if you don't need them. Alternatively write your program to only list files, or even files of the specific type you are looking for. For example, use DOS type commands in Windows, executing

```
dir /a:-d
```

will show only files in the directory but not the '.' and '..' entries.
while

```
dir *.txt
```

would list only .txt files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above '.' represents the current directory. While '..' represents the parent directory. Windows represents them as links.

Incidentally, if ur in a root directory then windows (cmd prompt mode) considers '.' and '..' as one and same.

of course in windows explorer the following dont hold good. there if u go to parent directory of say C:\ then u reach the My computer.